# Script to Log Shutdowns and Reboots

Tags: scripting

I am trying to create a script that will run daily as a cronjob and log all shutdowns and reboots. I've come up with this, but the grep seems to be ignored, and the script results in the output of `last -x shutdown reboot`.

```
set ydate = $(date --date yesterday “+%b %d”)
last -x shutdown reboot | grep "$ydate" >>/var/log/down
```

How can I make this capture only the reboots and shutdowns of the previous day?

Comment: What language is your script in? Is that supposed to be `sh`/`bash`?

Comment: What do those double quote marks really look like in your script?

Comment: Take a look at my answer and it's comments. It could be the day padding question on your date output.

Answer (score 3):

This could be a solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
YEST=$(date "--date=${today} -1 day" +%Y%m%d235959)
YEST_ONLY=$(date "--date=${today} -1 day" +"%b %e")
last -t $YEST -x shutdown reboot | grep "$YEST_ONLY"
```

- First line: Make a date output of yesterday, and format as `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS`. This is how `last` expect as a format to `-t` argument
- Second Line: Create a `Mon DD` format of yesterday. Why? Because `-t` from `last` does not search for a specific date. It will get a time and search for that time **and** older entries.
- Finally, make `last` show yesterday and older `shutdown` and `reboot` logs, grep yesterday as filter.

And yes. I agree that `last` could have a date argument to a specific day.

Comment: Aaaaaaaaaaaaand just now, i saw that i could have ignored the `-t` option and just grep'ed `$YEST_ONLY`. Learn kids, excess of coffee can make you overthink and put layers not needed to your code ...

Comment: I agree with you about last but I see a possible problem, last shows dates between 01-09 as Mar  3 not Mar 03.

Comment: That's easy. Just change `%d` to `%e`, and you will have the day output with padding. Let me change the script.

Comment: I'm getting "last: invalid time value '-x'". I've tried a few modifications, but I can't get last to take $YEST as an input.

Comment: What about if  you run the script with shell debug ? `bash -x script.sh` . Put the output on pastie or pastebin.

Comment: http://pastie.org/private/ksko1g4ohwqn0avxsjkcgg

Comment: You may have some issue on your `-t ` parameter. What is the value you are using? It should be `last -t $ydate -x shutdown reboot`. Cheers

Comment: I am using last -t $ydate -x shutdown reboot | grep "$ydate_only". Thanks

Comment: Could you please remove the `set` in front of the variables, letting something like: `ydate = $(date --date yesterday "+%b %d")`. `set` is not needed on your case ;)

Comment: I removed them. Now I get two changes in the debug run: + ydate_only='Mar 18' and + grep 'Mar 18'. However, I still get 'last: Invalid time value "-x".